How to change golang Electron.js Application's app menu on macOS?
I am using go-astilectron along with Electron.js to build a desktop application.
I am done creating the app, yet I am having an issue with the app menu (provided by the system on the top left-most corner).
When I run the app on macOS, I get the app menu which has the correct name (my application name) but when I click it, I get the options (About Electron, Hide Electron, Quit Electron, .. etc).
How can I modify that to hold my application's name instead of Electron so that the options would be (About myApp, Hide myApp, Quit myApp ...etc).
Also, I want to add more information to the 'About' section so that it is displayed once that option is clicked.
Any thoughts on that ?
I have tried modfying the Info.plist file located under the created 'vendor' directory under electron package/myApp/Contents.
I modified the line that contained the deafault version of Electron by default (11.4.3), to the version of my app, and I have seen that change in when I clicked the about choice.

Reading the docs is always a good idea. Can you modify the app's Electron JavaScript source though, or is everything generated by some tool?
